# commandLink disabled via javascript can still be clicked

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, tomahawk

I need to disable the button based on the selected row of t:dataTable. 
This is the javascript method I'm calling on the row selection event
(the button should be disabled if an item in the selected row has a tooltip... it's ugly, but it was the easiest thing to do):

```
function processUpdateButton() {
if (!$(".selectedRow").length
    || $(".selectedRow").children().find(".tooltip").length){
    $(".Update").button({disabled:true});
} else {
    $(".Update").button({disabled:false});
};
}
```

This is the JSF commandLink:

```
<h:commandLink id="update" styleClass="Update iconButton"
             action="#{myBB.update}"
             value="#{gui['button.update']}"
             tabindex="301"/>
```

Setting disabled attribute to the button works. The button is greyed out and if I hover the mouse over it, the cursor doesn't change as it does for other links. The problem is, that I can still click it and the method in the backing bean is called. Is there some way to prevent that?
Here's the rendered disabled button:

```
<a id="mainForm:update" 
    class="iconButton ... ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled"
    onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('mainForm','mainForm:update');" 
    href="#" role="button" aria-disabled="true" disabled="disabled">
      <span class="ui-button-text">Update</span>
</a>
```

I should probably remove the onClick attribute, but I don't know how I would be able to reenable it again.

Of course I can check the condition on the server after clicking the Update button, but that's the last resort. It would be nice if I could completely disable the button generated by JSF only from javascript without call to the server.

Comment: Your "last resort" is your only option. The component's state is maintained server-side. So your javascript update of the `disabled` attribute will still need to be communicated to the server somehow for the runtime to respect it

Comment: That's true. But I only want to prevent user from triggering the event. See my solution below. I know it's not very safe(as the server would still process the event when someone hacks the element manually), but that's not a problem in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found the solution. I copied the onclick attribute to another attribute on disabling button and vice versa:

```
var onclick;
if (!$(".selectedRow").length
    || $(".selectedRow").children().find(".tooltip").length){
    $(".Update").button({disabled:true});
    onclick=$(".Update").attr('onclick');
    $(".Update").attr('onclick2',onclick);
    $(".Update").removeAttr('onclick');
} else {
    $(".Update").button({disabled:false});
    onclick=$(".Update").attr('onclick2');
    $(".Update").attr('onclick',onclick);
    $(".Update").removeAttr('onclick2');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the generated html code is not a button but hyperlink. So you need to remove the link from link tag. Could try follows:

```
$(".Update").removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. But it's still a mystery, that the cursor in the browser doesn't change as it does for other hyperlinks.

Comment: It's the same. href is gone, but I can still click it. I think I need to disable the onClick event, but I don't know how to do that in a way that I'll be able to reenable it.

Comment: Could try, .removeAttr('onclick');

Comment: That works, but I'll loose the onclick event generated by JSF. That's a problem since I want to be able to reenable it and if I then do something like 
```$(".Update").attr('onclick', 'return myfaces.oam.submitForm('mainForm','mainForm:update');')```, I fear that the code will be very fragile and surely breaks in the future. I'd like to only hide the generated onclick event, but I'm not sure how